# CAST string to TIMESTAMP(0) in teradata

Tags: sql, database, teradata, teradatasql

I have a string of timestamp as `27/Mar/2023:15:36:58 +0900`

I want to cast it to timezone(0) preserving the timestamp info.

I am trying to run following SQL but it fails saying Invalid Timestamp

```
CAST('27/Mar/2023:15:36:58 +0900' AS TIMESTAMP(0) WITH TIME ZONE FORMAT 'DD/MMM/Y4:HH:MI:SSBZ')
```

Is there any way to pass custom timezone hours format to CAST function.

Comment: Don't think `+0900` is correct for time zone - you need `+09:00`. +HH:MI

Comment: Localized timestamp literals are of a form `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SSPho:mo` where the P is either a plus sign or minus sign and ho and mo are the hours and minute offset from UTC you want to specify.  The format is quite rigid and finicky.

Comment: Or `to_timestamp_tz(x,'dd/mon/yyyy:hh24:mi:ss tzhtzm')` works, but returns TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE and reducing time/timestamp precision is something else that can be finicky. Probably better to modify the string format and then CAST.

Comment: @Fred `To_Timestamp_Tz` throwing error `unknown character in date`